# How to force/ close a socket connection in php

Tags: php, sockets, telnet

I have an issue with a project, I'm connecting to a remote server using telnet , i'm able to retrieve the console text and store it in a array and the to a database, all that fine, the problem is the telnet server keeps the session opened for 1:30 minutes so i get the output until 1:30 minutes, i want to retrieve the console text and force the php telnet connection but i don't know how, i tried everything and the sessions keeps opened.

Any help would be appreciated

```
<?php


$ip= $argv[1];

$da = fsockopen($ip, 23, $errno, $errstr, $timeout=3);

if (!$da){

       echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";

} else {

    $output = "\data\r\n";
  

    fwrite($da, $output);
    while (!feof($da))
    {
          
          $str = fgets($da, 1024);
          $a = explode(" ", $str);
          $myJSON = json_encode($a,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
          print var_dump($a);
          print_r($a);
          
    }
    stream_set_timeout($da, 1); 
    fclose($da);
    }

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Does it disconnect if you send `exit\r` to it?

Comment: The problem may not be how to force the end of the transmission, but how to know that the data has been transmitted. If the data terminal can tell you that the data transmission has been completed, without waiting for more data, then you don’t need to wait for `feof` to return `true` to exit the loop.

Comment: *When* do you want to close the connection?

Comment: The text terminal is store from fgets always, i just want to retrieve that text store it in a variable and close the connection immediately